# PHP - Using $_POST after a link

Tags: php, post

I have a form with a textbox with name="name".

In my code, I use a direct image hosted on another website in the format:

$grav_url = "http://yourwebsitehere.com/avatarimage.php?username=YourUsername";

I want the YourUsername part to be replaced with the input of the textbox.

For this to work, i'm trying the following code:

$grav_url = "http://yourwebsitehere.com/avatarimage.php?username="+ $_POST['name'];

What am I doing wrong? PHP noob here

Comment: Are you really POSTing something using form? 
Where is that HTML form code.

Comment: Are you trying to use `+` to concatenate strings in PHP? `.` is the PHP concatenation operator

Comment: Hey! Concatenation operator in PHP is `.` and not `+`
`$grav_url = "http://yourwebsitehere.com/avatarimage.php?username=" . $_POST['name'];`

Comment: @Downvoter, please consider leaving a comment. I am  upvoting to reset it back to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php . is used for concatenate string not +

here try this

```
$grav_url = "http://yourwebsitehere.com/avatarimage.php?username=".$_POST['name'];
```